# Magento tier price round off

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I'm using Magento 1.4.1.1

I set up a tier price in admin panel and its working well.

The problem is in the shopping cart, it displays only 2 decimal places.

Example: 
In my backend I set up a tier price 0.211 but when I check it in the shopping cart, it displays 0.21. By that, it creates a computation problem.
Like when the price is 0.210 and I ordered 250pcs the answer is 52.50,
Unlike when the price is 0.211 and I ordered 250pcs the answer is 52.75.
So there is a computation difference.

I want that the price in the shopping cart to be the same on the tier price that I set up.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks and Have a Good Day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your question: yes you can, but you have to change the code on many different files in magento, here you'll find more answers: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/16337/ Don't forget to keep your magento system update proof!